# Getting old bluetooth headset out of standby on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, headset

I think this is the problem, and if not, I'm open to suggestions. I have an old Jabra BT200 that I used to use on my phone. When a phone call was coming in it would beep using its own noises (meaning the phone never rang inside the headset) and then I could push the 'answer/hang up' button and sound and mic would start working. I have now paired it with Windows 7, and it looks good. Under the playback menu I have 'Bluetooth Hands free Audio / Jabra BT200 (Mono Audio) / Ready', and under the recording menu I have 'Bluetooth Audio Input Device / Jabra BT200 (Mono Audio) / Ready'. However when I try to test the speakers Windows sends a sound, but I never hear it, and when I talk in the mic, Windows never hears me.
If I right click either the Bluetooth mic or speakers there's an option to 'Connect', but it's grayed out and I cannot click it. As the final piece of knowledge I have, my headset blinks once every 3 seconds when it's in standby and I can't get that to change. If everything was working it should blink once every second at which point I think all of my problems would be fixed. Hence my issue: I can't seem to get my headset out of standby. On my headset I've tried sending it test noises and then pressing the 'Answer' button, but still nothing. The headset beeps when I press it, so it works, it just doesn't ever come out of standby. Is there maybe some way to trick my headset into thinking it's getting a phone call from my computer?

Answer (score 0):

My Jabra is similar. To use it, I have to push the headset button first -- when I do that, the device becomes the primary sound device, and then things like Skype work well.

While in a call I can push the headset button to end that call. If I push the button when not in a call, the button ends the audio service instead -- and the normal PC speakers are primary sound device again.